# What is the best way to install KDE in Arch without installing all the KDE applications?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, kde, sd-card, plasma5

I want to avoid installing many of the KDE applications when I install KDE. So far I have been avoiding any of the meta packages related to KDE applications and simply installing only those applications I know I will use. However, I have been told that is *not a good practice*.

My question is:

**What is the right way to install KDE in Arch without installing any of these applications?**

- games
- accessibility tools
- edu packages
- dragon
- elisa
- juk
- kamoso
- grantlee-editor
- kmail
- sweeper
- kteatime
- kfloppy
- kbackup
- cervisia
- umbrello

Those are all the groups / applications I wish to **not** install. Usually, I install even less, but there are some meta packages I can live with.

Comment: In which context have you been told that installing selected application packages only is not a good practice? It sounds weird, especially on Arch Linux. And... you haven't been told what the good practice is?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the context of the advice I gave before for this quote

> To avoid getting things I did not want, I installed the KDE apps
>   explicitly.
>
> pacman -S plasma-workspace plasma-desktop systemsettings kwin kdelibs
>   kdebase-kdialog kde-gtk-config systemd-kcm kdesu krename kate kwrite
>   retext kdegraphics-okular xdg-utils plasma-nm drkonqi kdeplasma-addons
>   kscreen ksshaskpass ksysguard kwallet-pam user-manager firefox kompare
>   kdiff3 gtk3 gimp gimp-ufraw xsane xsane-gimp gwenview qt5-imageformats
>   kimageformats kcharselect kcolorchooser kdebase-keditbookmarks dolphin
>   dolphin-plugins kdeutils-kdf ark spectacle pulseaudio plasma-pa
>   kdemultimedia-kmix pulseaudio-alsa pavucontrol libdvdcss
>   kwalletmanager kio-extras konsole kdebase-lib gnupg kdeutils-kgpg
>   gnome-themes-standard xclip print-manager

Installing packages explicitly like this would leave your system with deprecated packages that could cause you problems in the future. e.g here in your case

`kdebase kdegraphics-okular kdebase-keditbookmarks kdeutils-kdf kdemultimedia-kmixkdebase-keditbookmarks kdeutils-kdf kdemultimedia-kmix kdebase-lib kdeutils-kgp`

are replaced with newer packages.

So, to install KDE properly, you should either use **-meta** packages or **groups**. I highly recommend the -meta package approach because groups can’t enforce installation of packages when being extended or modified.

If you insist in tuning your system, use the groups and you have to do the cleaning yourself but still much better than the very low level you are currently doing.

Comment: cc @MountainX-for-Monica That's why context is important ;-) Totally right, explicitly installing packages that would be otherwise pulled in as dependencies is not a good idea, for the reasons you outlined. Nevertheless, I think there is still no need to install a full _applications_ meta-package or group. Sure, you should probably install `plasma-meta`—manually selecting its top level dependencies would be just a pointless headache—but nothing prevents you from installing a selected list of applications. Just avoid _explicitly_ installing packages that are dependencies of other packages.

Comment: @fra-san - thanks. Also it isn't as bad as Munzir Taha suggests because over the years as package names change or one package replaces another, the normal Arch update process notifies the user and provides update options. Furthermore, using normal Arch package maintenance (such as checking for orphaned packages) has shown me that my process has not resulted in any of the suggested issues in over 5 years of use on many different devices running Arch.

Comment: I see what Munzir Taha did in this answer. He took a command I used 5 years ago and suggested that's the exact command I would use today. Not correct. With Arch you don't have to re-install. Over the last five years the update process did not result in the problem Munzir Taha suggests. My system is currently up to date without any orphaned or deprecated packages.

Comment: I'm going to stick with what has worked for five years and has kept my system free of the games and other packages I don't want.

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica: Please, don't remove the context of my answer because it would be confusing. I don't know you 5 years ago, you sent me a command some days ago in a chat session and asked me to explain why it's not good practice.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that this works quite well

```
sudo pacman -R `pacman -Qqs kde games`
```

replace games with the category you want

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am not asking how to remove. I am asking how to explicitly initially only install the desired KDE packages while avoiding any of the meta packages related to KDE applications.